# Github website publish cannot publish unborn HEAD

Tags: git, github

I cannot publish a bootstrap website from my local computer through Github desktop. It states: `cannot publish unborn head`

What does it mean? What changes should I make?

Comment: Have you committed your code?

Comment: Thanks, I’ve found the problem.. I haven’t included read me files..

Comment: And you can't publish if you got nothing to publish.

Answer (score 16):

The reason is that your repository is empty and you should make at least a readme file. It worked in my case.

Answer (score 11):

**cannot publish unborn HEAD**

This issue occurs because your github repository is empty i.e without a single file.Below is the snapshot.

[image]

2 ways to fix this,

1. While creating repository initialize with default readme file.

[image]

2. Or create a new readme file after repository is created(without readme file).

git init

git add README.md

git commit -m "first commit"

git remote add origin https://github.com/hameedshk/test-stackoverflow.git

git push -u origin master

Answer (score 7):

You have to commit something to publish the repository.

Answer (score 5):

The solution for me was to add some text in the 'summary' area (lower left hand corner of Github desktop GUI).

Comment: I did the same and it worked. I had files in the repo as well as the README but still came across the error in GitHub Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a file in your local repo before, you publish into github.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it will be useful to someone.

Note whether the file from your repository is open in the IDE, and if it is open, close it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you have created your repo locally using `git init` first thing you need to do is to add files to commit by `git add .` and then execute `git commit -m 'commit message here'`. Then you can execute

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/yourUserName/yourRepo.git
  git branch -M main
  git push -u origin main
```

And your changes will be in your remote repo

*TLDR: just commit your changes*

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

To push you need something to push. It is a commit. Just create like `git add . && git commit -m Repository init`.

You also can create `.gitignore` file and push it together with commit.

For example:

1 `git init` - init git

2 `git remote add origin <path.git>` - add record to remote repo as "origin" link

3 `git branch -M master` - set default branch name

4 `touch .gitignore` - create file. Edit it as you want.

5 `git add .` - add all uncommited files, watches gitignore

6 `git commit -m Repository init` - create commit to push

7 `git push -u origin master` - push commits (changes) and set up-stream to master branch.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you are pushing only content e.g images of something. Make sure you have some text file in Git repo folder and then retry